# What is the meaning of: merging with Brahman after Moksha?

Tags: brahman, moksha

We know that we undergo multiple incarnation until we get Moksha, then we get merged with Brahman after Moksha, and then there's no incarnation.

What is the meaning of merging with Brahman?.

Is this a kind of eternal life without body?

If Brahman is impersonal, then what is the meaning of merging with impersonal entity?

Is this kind of life eternal?, Or till the time of paralay?

Comment: Merging with Brahman and Moksha are same. Not after or different. Where there's no individual identity of Jiva. Where there's no second exists aside Brahman. Brahman alone exists. Its the state of moksha which mean merging with Brahman.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti I prefer definite philosophic speech not rhetorical speech. The idea of: Brahman alone exists and Jivas are actually Brahman is philosophically and logically flimsy.

Comment: There's no logic exists there. The state of no mind to understand nor intellect, everything dissolves into that one. Shiva sutras say Atma chittam.

First there's identification of "Iam in world". Second "I am the knower of all actions. I am not this changing activities but instead Iam knower of this activities"

Third " Iam the jagat" realisation dawns where all perceptions, differentiated ideas are dropped when one realises there's no identity, it is only God, the Brahman.

Then this state of realisation also dissolves. Brahman alone remains. Purest existential form.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti Thanks for sharing, I speak about ontological necessity, i.e: Plurality in existence is ontological necessity. Godhead is male and female, Godhood are levels and the creation is plural Jivas, all these items are of ontological necessity.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti I think, if I am not sure, that Brahman is not selfish. I think He will do his best for the Jivas to keep their identities. The story of Mind and Consciousness and the difference between both of them is ontological necessity.

Comment: Merging is not said its about oneness in veda's in a sense that all souls along with brahman are in same place or near to brahman not all souls became one with god.. its like pandva army soldiers have all become one against kauravas in gurskshetra. then if you construe that this one is nothing but pandvas army became one person army is foolish argument, similar sense should be carefully applied for god, jiva can never be one with god or equal in any aspect to god..

Comment: @PrasannaR mode of Perfection of Brahman is just One possibility of Perfection modes, as I mentioned in another question. This mean that some Jivas are less Perfection mode than Brahman, some equals Brahman and some may excel or exceed or surpass Brahman mode of Perfection. What matters for Brahman is to know his exact mode of Perfection, and the totality of Jivas equal Brahman but not in additive manner.

Comment: @salah you have to explore the identity to see if in reality it exists or not. It is fear of losing individuality is what makes one bonded in this cycle of birth and death. This individuality is the bondage of ahamkar, the ego with gross body.

Comment: The identity is nothing but bunch of thought pattern one has created for himself. This is generating Karma. Drop the sense of I, along with all these thoughts drop. What remains there, is eternal with no identity

Comment: https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/parables/1_files/1-176.html Jiva is like a fly, Brahman is the ocean of bliss.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti I easily accept changing my mind, changing my Ideas, changing my thoughts but I never accept changing my Identity, I never accept changing my name. Losing your Identity is Moksha is false teaching in Hinduism. Creating real and genuine Identity is Moksha, and this is the mission of God. God's gift to his sons is to donate them real and genuine Identities.

Comment: @salah its not changing your ideas or thoughts. Just ask what is the identity. Individuality is what you need to enquire and see if it really exists. If it doesnt exist and appears to exist is like "Sky appearing in blue is real or not"

Answer (score 2):

> What is the meaning of: merging with Brahman after Moksha?

According to Shankaracharya, the individual self (Jivatma) literally becomes Brahman. [But according to Ramanujacharya](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48555.htm), the Jivatma acquires a nature similar to Brahman, but keeps its own separate identity while having the knowledge that Brahman is its Antaryami:

> The consciousness of the released soul therefore expresses itself in the following form: 'I am Brahman, without any division.' Where the texts speak of the soul's becoming equal to, or having equal attributes with, Brahman, the meaning is that the nature of the **individual soul--which is a mere mode of Brahman**--is equal to that of Brahman, i.e. that on putting off its body it becomes equal to Brahman in purity.

This is what it means to "merge with Brahman" according to Ramanujacharya.

> Is this kind of life eternal?

Yes it is. The last sutra of the Brahma sutras is:

> anAvrtti shabdAt, anAvrtti shabdAt
>
> Non-return, according to Scripture; non-return, according to Scripture.

Which means the released soul will not return to samsara; it will be in the state of moksha for eternity.

> ... without body?

The released soul has a choice to be with or without body, and change it whenever it wants to.

> Reverend Bâdarâyana is of the opinion that the Released may, at his liking, be with or without a body.

Answer (score 0):

Namaste.those are all missconceptions.And the real liberation does not mean merge into impersonal Brahman .that's not even our constitutional position ,as we are eternal servant of God ,Govinda, Krishna ....So our goal is to go back to him, to serve him.
Brahmajyoti its his external effulgence. the energy of creation ,its not the Ultimate and its not eternal.
The Spiritual World Vaikunta e Goloka is eternal.
pls read here https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/28/17/.Blessings

Comment: Sir, you can follow whatever philosophy you like but rejecting others' philosophy is not the way

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [Tour](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35177)